# How to make a collision system for a list of points and polygons in desmos?

Tags: desmos

So, I'm trying to make a basic shooter game in desmos, and I have a list of points that act as bullets. The (current) enemies right now are only some triangular jets that fly in a linear manner. My current goal is:

1. Make it so when the point hits the triangle, it deletes itself from the list, and thus itself from the screen as well.
2. The Triangle, upon getting hit, moves downwards in a curved path and stops when it hits the ground (a line).

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sjezpkhhxl

Here is the graph itself. The lines for the bullets themselves are in the folder titled bullet and the lines for the triangle are labelled as enemy: fighter jets.

If any more details are needed, please do let me know.